# Html file avaliable from request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to confirm ownership of domain, as instruction says, place special `.html` file in main directory.

It confused me. Tutorial says, that file should be avaliable as `www.domain.com/file.html`

I placed it in views folder, but nothing. I wouldn't like to set special controller-action-route for that(it is quite weird), but looks like I should? Or other way?

How do I do that in terms of Rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `file.html` under the **public** folder, and visit `www.domain.com/file.html`

In Rails everything within the public folder is visible to the outside world.